# Rails 4: Reload page with ajax after submitting remote form to a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I've made a comments section for my 'posts' views and I've got `remote: true` working on the form so when you hit enter and submit the 'new comment' form to the database, it updates in the background fine (the comment is created, page doesn't redirect or change) but I can't get it to load the comments on the page. You have to refresh the page to see them.

I could do `redirect_to :back` in the comments controller after saving but that takes user to top of the page rather than staying put to see the comment appear.

I've tried `render 'posts#show'` after saving the comment in the comment controller create action but that tries to send you to `/comments/posts/:slug/`. If it actually rendered the posts show action I think this would work.

Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_commentable

  def show
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
    @comment.author = current_user if current_user
    @comment.save
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :author_id, :post_id)
    end

    def find_commentable
      @commentable = Comment.find(params[:comment_id]) if        params[:comment_id]
      @commentable = Post.find_by_slug(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
    end
  end
```

Comment section on post show view:

```
%ul#post-comments
  = render 'comment_feed'

  = form_for [@post, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|
    = f.text_field :body, class: 'js-new-comment-field', placeholder: "Write a comment..."
```

posts/show.js.erb:

```
$("#post-comments").html("<%= escape_javascript render("comment_feed") %>");
```

Routes.rb:

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      match 'search' => 'posts#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search # For ransack search
    end
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments do
    resources :comments # Replies on comments
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

This helped loads: 
https://gemfile.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/rails-blog-comments-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I added this second match line to routes.rb and it's refreshing the page with the new comment now:

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      match 'search' => 'posts#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
      match '/comments/posts/:slug' => 'posts#show', via: [:get, :post], as: :comment
    end
    resources :comments
  end
```

It's not ajax though: [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEqUa.gif)

Comment: did you got solution?

Comment: Not yet but a bit closer. I'm not doing anything server side so maybe I just need to figure out how to respond to the ajax request with the comment it creates. This page is helpful so far http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html